# Keeping number of threads constant with pthread in C

Tags: linux, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I tried to find a solution in order to keep the number of working threads constant under linux in C using pthreads, but I seem to be unable to fully understand what's wrong with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_JOBS 50
#define MAX_THREADS 5

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int jobs = MAX_JOBS;
int worker = 0;
int counter = 0;

void *functionC() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  worker++;
  counter++;
  printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

  // Do something...
  sleep(4);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  jobs--;
  worker--;
  printf(" >>> Job done: %d\n",jobs);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i=0, j=0;
  pthread_t thread[MAX_JOBS];

  // Create threads if the number of working threads doesn't exceed MAX_THREADS
  while (1) {
    if (worker > MAX_THREADS) {
      printf(" +++ In queue: %d\n", worker);
      sleep(1);
    } else {
      //printf(" +++ Creating new thread: %d\n", worker);
      pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &functionC, NULL);
      //printf("%d",worker);
      i++;
    }
    if (i == MAX_JOBS) break;
  }

  // Wait all threads to finish
  for (j=0;j<MAX_JOBS;j++) {
    pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
  }

  return(0);
}
```

A while (1) loop keeps creating threads if the number of working threads is under a certain threshold. A mutex is supposed to lock the critical sections every time the global counter of the working threads is incremented (thread creation) and decremented (job is done). I thought it could work fine and for the most part it does, but weird things happen...

For instance, if I comment (as it is in this snippet) the printf //printf(" +++ Creating new thread: %d\n", worker); the while (1) seems to generate a random number (18-25 in my experience) threads (functionC prints out "Counter value: from 1 to 18-25"...) at a time instead of respecting the IF condition inside the loop. If I include the printf the loop seems to behave "almost" in the right way... This seems to hint that there's a missing "mutex" condition that I should add to the loop in main() to effectively lock the thread when MAX_THREADS is reached but after changing a *LOT* of times this code for the past few days I'm a bit lost, now. What am I missing?

Please, let me know what I should change in order to keep the number of threads constant it doesn't seem that I'm too far from the solution... Hopefully... :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have your answer "This seems to hint that there's a missing "mutex" condition that I should add to the loop in main()" : lock the mutex before reading your shared values ...

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `worker` is not incremented until the new thread actually starts and gets to run - in the meantime, the main thread loops around, checks `workers`, finds that it hasn't changed, and starts another thread.  It can repeat this many times, creating far too many threads.

So, you need to increment `worker` in the main thread, when you've decided to create a new thread.

You have another problem - you should be using condition variables to let the main thread sleep until it should start another thread, not using a busy-wait loop with a `sleep(1);` in it.  The complete fixed code would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_JOBS 50
#define MAX_THREADS 5

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int jobs = MAX_JOBS;
int workers = 0;
int counter = 0;

void *functionC() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  counter++;
  printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

  // Do something...
  sleep(4);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  jobs--;
  printf(" >>> Job done: %d\n",jobs);

  /* Worker is about to exit, so decrement count and wakeup main thread */
  workers--;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i=0, j=0;
  pthread_t thread[MAX_JOBS];

  // Create threads if the number of working threads doesn't exceed MAX_THREADS
  while (i < MAX_JOBS) {
    /* Block on condition variable until there are insufficient workers running */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    while (workers >= MAX_THREADS)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &mutex1);

    /* Another worker will be running shortly */
    workers++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &functionC, NULL);
    i++;
  }

  // Wait all threads to finish
  for (j=0;j<MAX_JOBS;j++) {
    pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Note that even though this works, it isn't ideal - it's best to create the number of threads you want up-front, and have them loop around, waiting for work.  This is because creating and destroying threads has significant overhead, and because it often simplifies resource management.  A version of your code rewritten to work like this would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_JOBS 50
#define MAX_THREADS 5

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int jobs = MAX_JOBS;
int counter = 0;

void *functionC()
{
  int running_job;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  counter++;
  printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);

  while (jobs > 0) {
    running_job = jobs--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

    printf(" >>> Job starting: %d\n", running_job);

    // Do something...
    sleep(4);

    printf(" >>> Job done: %d\n", running_job);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;
  pthread_t thread[MAX_THREADS];

  for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &functionC, NULL);

  // Wait all threads to finish
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your replies, this is exactly what I was missing. Everyone have a blessed day! :-)

Comment: Hello @caf ! I need also to limit number of my threads in my application. But instead of 50 jobs I have ~3.000.000 Jobs. Which solution would you suggest: 1st or 2nd? In my opinion it makes sense to take the 1st Solution with its constant overhead and not the 2nd due heavy management of 3 Mio. simultaneously started threads. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MaxWie: In the code in this question, "jobs" are the number of work items to be processed - there's 50 jobs but only 5 threads.  Note that both methods can create up to `MAX_THREADS` threads at once, so there is no difference to the overhead there.  I would use the second method, but 3 million threads sounds quite excessive.